# docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 while installing ArangoDB via Docker on M1 Mac

Tags: docker, arangodb, apple-m1

When you try and install ArangoDB via Docker:

`docker run -e ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 8529:8529 -d --name arangodb arangodb`

The following error is thrown:

```
Unable to find image 'arangodb:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/arangodb
docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To resolve this you have to set the platform for docker to x86_64, atleast for the time being:

`docker run -e ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 8529:8529 -d --platform linux/x86_64/v8 --name arangodb arangodb`

Comment: Meanwhile ArangoDB 3.10 onwards comes with ARM64 docker containers and compatible Apple ARM binaries.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a while installing mysql 5.7, I used below command,

```
docker pull mysql:5.7 --platform linux/x86_64/v8
```